# Ошибка при попытке открыть локальную базу данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, asp.net

У меня есть проект в Visual Studio на C#, Web-приложение ASP.NET.

Я пытаюсь получить диаграмму базы данных, но при попытке открыть таблицы в обозревателе серверов происходит ошибка:

[image: 1]

Вот строчка из `Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestManagementTools-20170329041919.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestManagementTools-20170329041919;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас проблема не со строкой подключения. У Вас Visual Studio ругается на отсутствующую сборку. Последняя, скорее всего, либо не установлена вообще, либо установлена некорректно.